# Do I need a 48V switch for a voltage divider circuit?

Tags: mosfet, voltage-divider, toggle-switch

I need to use a rocker switch to turn on a MOSFET. I wanted to use a MOSFET to control when the current flows because I don't want to use a large switch to handle a large amount of current.

This is a simplified circuit showing the main concept. Since this switch is part of a voltage divider circuit, would I need to select one that's rated for 48, or would I be able to get a way with using a switch that is rated for (at least) 36V, per this example?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG8V7p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: When the switch is open, what is the voltage across it?

Comment: Ah, okay. It would be 48V. If I flipped the switch to where it's 0V when it's open, what about that?

Comment: You mean swap SW1 and R2? Why would that make any difference?

Comment: You could put it in parallel with R1, in which case it would have either 0V or 12V across it.

Comment: @Finbarr No, I meant rotate the switch 180 degrees to where it's 0V when open, and 36V when closed. Opposed to 48V when open, and 36V when closed.

Comment: If it has 48V across it now, it'll still have 48V across it if you rotate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current configuration, and in fact any series configuraiton, when the switch is open, you'll have the full 48V across it -- no current flows through R1 or R2, so each drops no voltage, leaving the full drop across the switch.

If you don't mind wasting a small amount of power (not good for batteries, but OK for DC supply), then you could alter the topology to allow a switch for a lower rated voltage. By placing the switch in *parallel* with R1, you would still have the same 48V/36V gate drive depending on the switch position, and the maximum voltage seen by the switch will be the 12V -- this works because R2 is now always conducting a current and so always dropping some of the voltage. The switch of course has reverse meaning - closed = off, open = on.

Answer (score 2):

I think in actual practice you can pretty much ignore the voltage rating of the switch, at least for hobbyist use where nobody is going to question "approvals".

The DC voltage rating is based on the switch carrying significant current and the effects of the resulting arc on switch operation and contact life.

At 1.6mA **peak**, there will be no arcing of any significance. Any sensibly designed macroscopic switch can withstand 48V, and considerably more.

At STP the minimum breakdown voltage in air is 327V, and that for a rather small gap of 7.5um. Gaps smaller or larger have a higher breakdown voltage.